# Inject spring bean into @Controller via applicationContext.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` I defined a bean as follows:

```
<bean id="worplacementDAO" class="com.mycompany.maventestwebapp.db.dao">
            <property name="dataSource" value="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

Is it possible to inject the bean into a controller via `applicationContext` configuration file, without using `@Autowired`?

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `@Autowired`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer - **No.**

You can implement `BeanPostProcessor` to do something with your beans (e.g. inject dependency). Or you can manually register the bean as `<bean>` instead of letting `component-scan` do that for you. But that is all you can do.